# Inserting data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Stock Data

```
Batch Stock Rate 
------------------------
123---ABC---123 
251---XYZ---50
250---XYZ---55
247---XYZ---48
118---ABC---120
310---PQR---77
309---PQR---76
```

and the second table
Order Book

```
Date-------Stock---qty--Rate
--------------------------
2016-01-01---ABC---10---Null
2016-01-02---XYZ---25---Null
2016-01-03---PQR---18---Null
2016-01-04---XYZ---50---Null
```

I am stuck with inserting the Rate in the Order book table from Stock Data where the rate the in the stock data should be of the latest batch for each product. Thanks in advance

Comment: "Stock Data where the rate the in the stock data should be of the latest batch for each product" - can you make this more concrete and add an Example?

Comment: How do you define latest batch? greatest value of `Batch`?

Comment: @Philipp the rate for ABC should be 123 which has the latest batch number

Comment: So, do you want `UPDATE` query?

Comment: @Philipp, yes and update query

Comment: Could you please add the Expected `Rate` value in the `OrderBook` table as sample

Comment: Date-------Stock---qty--Rate
--------------------------
2016-01-01---ABC---10---123
2016-01-02---XYZ---25---50
2016-01-03---PQR---18---77
2016-01-04---XYZ---50---50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Query:-

```
UPDATE order_book ob, (
          SELECT rate, stock 
          FROM stock_data sd 
          GROUP BY stock 
          HAVING MAX(batch) 
          ORDER BY batch DESC
    ) result
SET ob.rate = result.rate
WHERE ob.stock = result.stock
```

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: Run This SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query:

```
UPDATE OrderBook OB
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        SD.Stock,
        SD.Rate
    FROM StockData SD
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            Stock,
            MAX(Batch) max_batch
        FROM StockData
        GROUP BY Stock
    ) AS t 
  ON SD.Stock = t.Stock AND SD.Batch = t.max_batch
) AS maxBatchRateTable 
ON OB.Stock = maxBatchRateTable.Stock
SET OB.Rate = maxBatchRateTable.Rate;
```

**Explanation:**

This query

```
    SELECT
        SD.Stock,
        SD.Rate
    FROM    StockData SD
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            Stock,
            MAX(Batch) max_batch
        FROM StockData
        GROUP BY Stock
    ) AS t 
  ON SD.Stock = t.Stock AND SD.Batch = t.max_batch
```

**finds the rate from the latest batch for each stock.**

Later if you make an `INNER JOIN` between this table and your `OrderBook` table on matching `Stock` and update the `Rate` in `OrderBook` table by the `rate` value returned by the above query you will get what you want.

Comment: Haha, had I used short aliases I could have been the first

Comment: Why did you delete your answer @Philipp. We started working at the same time. It's so likely that one may precede other. That's not a big deal. Hope you won't repeat this in future. :)

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: You can temporarily disable your safe update mode. `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` Then run the above update query

Comment: Actually the answer u accepted is not correct. That query might give expected output for the given input set. But there is no guarantee that it works right always. You can check by changing the order of ur data set say `250, 123...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
   order_book   
INNER JOIN
   (
      SELECT
         Rate,
         Stock   
      FROM
         stock_data  
      INNER JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               MAX(Batch) AS batch,
               stock    
            FROM
               stock_data    
            GROUP BY
               Stock  
         ) AS latestBatch    
            ON stock_data.Batch = latestBatch.batch 
            AND stock_data.stock = latestBatch.stock  
         ) AS updateData 
            ON updateData.Stock = order_book.Stock  
      SET
         order_book.Rate = updateData.Rate
```

Should be along those lines

Comment: Thanks for undoing the **delete**

Comment: Thought there was no need for the same query twice in the answers, but I guess it doesn't hurt either :)

Comment: Actually I think you can always make your answer **distinct** by adding more details. Doing that I believe your effort won't go in vain.